# Get terms parent ID for conditional IF statement

Tags: terms, php

I have the following working code to echo the name of the term (taxonomy called `prodcats`) that a series of posts are in. This is in the taxonomy archive template `taxonomy-prodcats.php`

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'prodcats' );
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '<div class="categoryblock">';
    echo '<h3>' . $term->name . '</h3>';
    echo '</div>';
    unset($term);
}
```

What I need to do is have the "categoryblock" div a different background color depending on what parent term is being used. There are 5 parent terms in total with IDs 3,4,5,6 and 7.

So, how do I adapt the above to say if this terms parent is 3, then echo x else if terms parent is 4, echo y else if terms parent is 5, echo z etc.. (you get the picture).

I tried several things including `$parent = $term->parent; echo $parent->id;` but this didn't output anything.

Comment: In the statement `$parent = $term->parent`, variable `$parent` wouldn't be an object but integer ( the parent ID ). So, you would just write out `echo $parent`;

Comment: Yes you are correct, OK so i've just inserted `$parent = $term->parent; echo $parent;` and it returned 3 which is the correct parent ID for what i'm testing this on.
So now how would if introduce the conditional part, would it be something like:
`if($parent == '3') :
echo 'do this';`

Comment: actually it's just easier to give the div `categoryblock` a second class with the id in and use CSS to amend such as `echo '<div class="categoryblock block' . $parent . '">';`

Comment: That will work just as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not specifically WordPress but some general PHP, here's a solution which you could use:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'prodcats' );
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $classes = 'categoryblock';

    switch( $term->parent ) {
        case 3:
            $classes .= ' blue'  // Notice the space between the opening string - important for CSS
          break;
    }

    echo '<div class="' . $classes . '">';
    echo '<h3>' . $term->name . '</h3>';
    echo '</div>';
    // unset( $term ); // I'm not sure this works and it would be unnecessary
}
```

So, we are using a PHP Switch at the top to append our class name to a string. Whenever a `$term->parent == 3` PHP will append `blue` to the string `$classes` so it will look like this: `categoryblock blue` which then will get added to the `<div/>` class attribute. This is assuming you have a `.blue{color:blue}` class in your CSS stylesheet.

On another note, there's no need to unset anything from your terms array unless you're going to be doing addition operations with that array later. [PHP Foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) will iterate through the array once from top to bottom.

Comment: Whilst this is not the solution i've gone for, it's the same sort of concept i my other comment so I thank you for your time, appreciate your help.